# jquery autocomplete отправлять id по значению поля

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Есть некая форма. В ней есть поле Регион, к которому прикручен jquery-ui autocomplete

```
    <input name="regionId" type="text" class="form-element-input" 
id="regions" placeholder="Введите регион" required />

    const regions = [
    {id: 1, label: 'Алтайский край'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Амурская область'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Архангельская область'},
    {id: 4, label: 'Астраханская область'},
    {id: 5, label: 'Белгородская область'}
  ];

  $( '#regions' ).autocomplete({
    source: regions
  });
```

На самом деле регионов в массиве значительно больше. Автокомплит отрабатывает правильно и при введении значения в поле появляются подсказки. Но задача в следующем: В момент сабмита формы происходит ajax-запрос с отправкой данных и нужно это значение преобразовать в соответствующий ему id из массива. То есть Алтайскому краю должно присвоиться значение 1 и т.п.

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/',
  data: {
    regionId: $('#regions').val(),
  },
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(result) {
    alert('Да');
  },
  error: function(result) {
    alert('неть');
  }
});
```

});

В данном коде regionId присваивается значение инпута. Как можно это значение преобразовать в нужный id перед отправкой запроса?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp - вот есть пример использования id и value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал функцию, которая пробегает массив, с введённым в инпут значением и выдаёт его id:

```
    function getValues(array, search) {
      return array.reduce(function(values, item){
        (item.label === search) && values.push(item.id);
        return values;
      }, []);
    }
```

Затем в переменную засовываю полученный id:

```
const regVal = getValues(regions, $('#regions').val())[0];
```